# A complex number inequality and the limitation

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

How to prove
$$|z-1|^\frac{1}{n}\ge||z|^\frac{1}{n} e^{\frac{1}{n}i\arg{z}}-1|,$$
for $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$ and 
$$|z-1|^\frac{1}{n}-||z|^\frac{1}{n} e^{\frac{1}{n}i\arg{z}}-1|\rightarrow 1$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Where $z$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to $$|z^n-1|\ge|z-1|^n$$, where $z$ is a complex number and $\arg{z}\in(0,\frac{\pi}{n})$.

Define the solution of $z^n-1=0$ by $\varsigma^k=\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}+i\sin{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$, where $k=0,1,2\cdots,n-1$.

We have $$z^n-1=(z-\varsigma)(z-\varsigma^2)\cdots(z-\varsigma^{n-1}).$$ Now, what we need to do is to prove $|(z-\varsigma^k)|\ge |z-1|$. In the view of  the geometric meaning of it, we see that $$|(z-\varsigma^k)|^2=|z|^2+1-2\cos{\big<z,\varsigma^k\big>}\ge |z|^2+1-2\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}$$ and 
$$|(z-1)|^2=|z|^2+1-2\cos{\big<z,1\big>}\le|z|^2+1-2\cos{\frac{\pi}{n}}.$$
It completes our proof.

And the limitation is easy to see. It can be see in the following website

[Inequality, triangle, Law of cosines， integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492518/inequality-triangle-law-of-cosines-integer/493217#493217)